# Why does Amazon Route 53 not support the .app tld?

Tags: amazon-route53, tld

I went to register a ".app" domain with Route 53 but I was told it was not available.

At first I thought this meant my domain was registered but after some digging it turns out that Amazon just doesn't support the .app tld.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=281421

Does Amazon need to pay to be a .app tld registrar? If so, maybe they are waiting until they get enough requests before they pay. It's not clear to me why Amazon would need to work for years to add support for a .app tld. I would think that it would involve just adding a .app value to some list of possible values.

Wikipedia mentions Google purchased the .app tld.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.app_(gTLD)

Does that mean adding support for the .app tld would mean paying Google?

Importantly does this impact my ability to link a .app domain (registered with Google) to any Amazon services?

Comment: Agreed, this is a pain

Answer (score 10):

I think the fact that Google acquired the .app TLD has surely something to do with this.

But you can use any domain that is registered somewhere else with AWS, if you are able to change the corresponding name servers.

Therefore you need to create a Hosted Zone for the domain in AWS Route 53. Then you go to your registrar and change the name servers of your domain to the values displayed in the newly created Zone from Route 53.